# How to open an saved excel document file location, and save the new info entered

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript

Does anyone know what type of script I could use to accomplish this task? I was thinking a VBS script or batch file could accomplish this...

I need it to open the excel document in the saved file location. Overwrite the file with new info..(my initials in cell D2) Then save the file under a new name in the same file location.

I'm no scripter, but if anyone could help me out with a script it would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: You are basically asking the Community to do the work for you. It is appropriate to show that you have a basis of the knowledge to get everyone with. A simple google search shows many answers to your issue. "edit excel document vbs"

Comment: There are millones of examples in the internet about writing to excel files

Comment: honestly don't see why you answered my question when your so negative about me asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my comment that i left. 
This is a **VERY** crude vbs that will get you started.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\temp\test.xls")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Test value"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\temp\newFile.xls"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close


objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: The question is way too broad for a reasonable answer here on SO, and might be deleted eventually. Please don't encourage bad questions by answering them.

Comment: Thanks matt for the help. This was exactly what I needed. All I did was edited the file location and what was inserted into the cells.

Comment: Also, I said in my post that I did not know how to to do VBS scripting and wasn't thinking I would get help this fast or any at all. I actually did try to research around for this for at least an hour. Which is why I went ahead and asked the question. So excuse the hell out of me for asking.